# Alter Mock<IType> object after .Object property has been called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, stubbing

I am currently writing unit tests and mocking a dependency using Moq framework. In doing this I have created a Mock like so:

```
Mock<ITraceProvider> traceProviderMock = new Mock<ITraceProvider>();
traceProviderMock.Setup(x => x.GetTraceContext(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("test");
ITraceProvider traceObj = traceProviderMock.Object;
```

However later on I want to modify the behaviour of the mock a little more so I call `Setup` on the Mock object again:

```
traceProviderMock.Setup(x => x.GetTracer(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("tracer");
```

Now without calling the `traceProviderMock.Object` again, will this new mock behaviour reflected in `traceObj`? That is what I would like to be the case.

This definitely works for the `Verify()` method but doesn't appear to for the `Setup` method.

The reason I want to do this, is due to the fact I have constructed a full dependency graph in the Test Setup method using a mocked dependency. I just want to change the behaviour of one of the mocked dependencies for my specific test. Subsequent tests would also apply their own specialisations to the mocked dependency.

Comment: Does the `GetTracer` method get set-up in your test setup method?

Comment: No, it is Setup in a specific test method. It is the test specific specialisation to the Mock if that makes sense.

Comment: I gave this a test, and it worked for me. I could set up the `GetTracer` method after getting the object from `traceProviderMock`, and it returned the expected value. Are you sure that your assertions are set up correctly? Can you step through the code in the debugger, if you haven't already?

Comment: I now have it working for me actually! It was working but the object I was testing was not actually running the method I was mocking I now realise. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This behaviour actually works as I expected it to. Due to an issue with my test, I was not actually calling the newly mocked method. This mislead me to believing the mocking framework was not behaving.

To summarise, you can change the mock after .Object has been called and the changes will be reflected in the mocked object instance.

Comment: Stumbled around wondering why Moq was not acting right, until reading this, reminding me to try some humble pie. Checked the dependent object, and turns out it was not using the Mock.Object as expected... my fault.